# Does `exec < somefile` behave the same as `source somefile`

Tags: bash, io-redirection, source, exec

```
$ cat somefile 
sleep 100
$ exec < somefile 
$ sleep 100
```

Does `exec < somefile` behave the same as `source somefile` except that its invoking process terminates upon its completion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effect is similar, but the behaviour isn’t strictly the same.

`exec < somefile` connects standard input to `somefile`, so the shell starts reading from that file instead of the terminal it’s currently connected to. (Well, at least bash does, Zsh behaves differently.) Effectively this results in the current shell processing the contents of `somefile`, as it would with `source somefile`. Once it has exhausted `somefile`, the shell exits.

Comment: Thanks. Effectively, does the shell always treat `somefile` in `exec < somefile` as a shell script?

Comment: In particular, an interactive Bash still prints the prompt when reading from the file if you do `exec < file`. And a _noninteractive_ shell might not read commands from `stdin` at all, so the redirection really only applies to any command the shell starts.

Comment: Yes, in the same way as running `bash somefile` (see the “ARGUMENTS” section in the manpage).